# Intellij React Native node_modules dependency breakpoint not hit

Tags: react-native, intellij-idea, react-navigation, expo, metro-bundler

I am using expo bare workflow (unimodules) and I would like to debug an issue by using breakpoints in `react-navigation-stack`, which lives under `node_modules`.

For coding and debugging I use Intellij. I have unchecked `Do not step into library scripts` and `Do not step into scripts`. I have also added `react-navigation-stack` as a library.

The problem is that my breakpoints for `react-navigation-stack` are ignored (they do not have a checkmark), but in `rn_range_slider` are hit normally (they have a checkmark).

Can anyone help?

Idea1:
It might have to do with metro's sourcemaps. I don't know how expo uses metro configuration and how to override it.

EDIT:

I added a photo from *react native debugger*, it seams metro loads `lib/module` target build, and breakpoints **work**
[image]

and from *IntelliJ*, `lib/module` breakpoints **work**, but `src/`(typescript) **do not**)
[image]

Comment: breakpoints in `node_modules` are resolved for me when debugging Expo bare workflow app in IDEA (using Android emulator). Not sure about `react-native-stack` though - what module is it? The only repo with similar name I've found is https://github.com/ahmeturganci/react-native-stack that doesn't look suitable.
Can you debug it in Dev Tools (see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#chrome-developer-tools)?

Comment: the module is https://github.com/react-navigation/stack

Comment: @lena I have added extra info (and edited some) after your comment